# Custom property editors not being registered for NetBeans 7.2 on JRE 1.7

Tags: java, java-7, slf4j, netbeans-platform

I have a large desktop Java application that is being moved from JRE 1.6 to JRE 1.7. The application uses the NetBeans API for GUI and the SLF4J API with a Log4J backend. The application has two deployment methods, a standalone application (run either by Ant or a Launch4j exe) or a web start via a simple custom HTTP server (Jetty and JNLP servlet).

The application has several NetBeans ModuleInstall components that add property editors onto the Java PropertyEditorManager search path at startup. E.g.

```
ArrayList<String> editorPaths = new ArrayList<String>();
editorPaths.add(LocationEditor.class.getPackage().getName());
editorPaths.addAll(Arrays.asList(PropertyEditorManager.getEditorSearchPath()));
PropertyEditorManager.setEditorSearchPath(editorPaths.toArray(new String[editorPaths.size()]));
```

When I migrated to Java 1.7 (u9) these editors were no longer being found in the application, either standalone or web start deployment. The application started fine and the editors were accessable when started from Eclipse. Curious to see why the standalone failed I added some logging statements to report the search path and set the *log4j.configuration* property via the Ant startup script. The editors were now available. I then launched the .exe (which doesn't accept command line parameters so the log4j configuration wasn't set) and the editors were gone again.

So the differentiator appears to be setting the log4j.configuration parameter. I changed the build so the standlong Ant and .exe referenced this and they work. The web start though doesn't pass this value on (it is loaded internally in the code) and still fails to find the editors. I also removed the log4j setting from the Eclipse run command and the editors vanish again.

I tried registering against type specifically rather than using the search path but still had no success. I'm using the search path as one optional overrides another modules editors but I don't know the module startup order, so that one appends its path to the start of the lookup while the others append to the end.

I've also tried removing all SLF4J to Log4J mappings and using the SLF4J-Simple instead. This made no difference. Adding the parameter back in makes the code work again. The spring-aspects dependency is pulling in a single Log4J reference.

I have a working solution for standalone and I'm sure I can get the new trick working for the webstart, but this reeks of a bad hack to get things working. I rather figure out the cause for the editors going missing. No exceptions are reported and removing logging from all ModuleInstall objects does nothing. All the code still executes, and this includes other features the ModuleInstall executes so I know they are running.

I'm using NetBeans RELEASE72 and the other dependencies are:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.2</version>
</dependency>
```

**Update 1**

I've tracked the problem down to our custom logging setup. When this section was removed and the simple logger used the problem didn't occur. When this custom configuration was removed and the slf4j-log4j12 connected again I still got the property editors. However when I enabled the custom logging configuration again the editors failed.

The custom logging configuration ensures we have a logging setup even if nothing is specified by the user. There is also some weird statup process that other users activated where the logging can't be activated until after a weaving process. I suspect that maybe the custom logging setting doesn't work with Java 1.7, or something to do with replacement of default logging handlers redirecting to our custom logging.

In any case it looks like an internal mess, not much the internet can help with.

Answer (score 1):

I'd left the problem and finally came back to it. The problem is that the PropertyEditorManager is now no longer a global singleton, but is a thread local singleton. The search path is registered in a ThreadLocalContext in JDK 1.7, presumably to prevent thread synchronisation issues. However the NetBeans ModuleInstall was being executed on the main thread, and then the property readers were being read on the AWT thread. This meant the AWT thread didn't find any of the property editors.

As a fix I just used the SwingUtilities.invokeLater() to register the property editor path.

I have no idea what caused the other symptons to show.

Answer (score 1):

I have just been tracing a similiar problem; 
when I run my NetBeans RCP 7.3 app under java 1.7.0_25 
`org.netbeans.beaninfo.editors.DateEditor` is no longer available to my GUI Property Sheets.

As you suggest, I have worked around the problem by including this code into my GUI module's Installer

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run() {
        NodeOp.registerPropertyEditors();
    }
});
```

This solves the problem for now, but it feels kind of hacky ...